# How to make a horizontal list view and then display bars on multiple items?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have successfully managed to make a scrollable horizontal "listview" with recyclerview adapter and it works perfectly.
it looks something like that:

|September|October|November|

|..................|............|................|

|..................|............|................|

|..................|............|................|

|..................|............|................|

Now I want to display some sort of a bar that will represent time frame, for instance, I have a time frame from mid-October til the end of November. So the bar needs to start in mid-October and ends in end November. It is also important to write a name on the bar.

I have thought I should implement another view so I could add this bars. How? I mean how do I even state that the bar should start at the beginning/end/middle of October...?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for showing us some context for your question, however this question is currently too open ended for the format here. Show us what you've tried specifically to create the time bar, and some of the code which creates your existing view.

Answer (score 0):

Take a advice ,and use RecycleView instead of Listview.And if i understant your question correct, u can use `linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset()` to scroll your recycle view to position you want!